# Share via option on Android 5.1

Tags: share-menu, file-sharing

When one selects the option to share a file on Android 5.1, there is list of apps populated by the OS.  Is the order of the list populated by Android based on most used apps? I have noticed this keeps changing time and time again. Can anyone help out as to what is the default criteria of order of this list populated by android. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is different in different roms, but in most cases apps will initially be sorted alphabetically and then by last used. The last used options will be at top.

Is there a specific reason you're asking this?